# 'reflectionCapabilities' of undefined Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

Hey so im just starting out with Angular 2 using webpack and im getting this error when trying to start the app up

> index.js:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'reflectionCapabilities' of undefined
>   which is this line here

```
core_private_1.reflector.reflectionCapabilities = new core_private_1.ReflectionCapabilities();
```

I guess it's something to do with my webpack build/dependancies

so here's my webpack config file which im using from a tutorial I was looking at

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='Run - Development' />
// An attempt at a very simple webpack config file that shows
//  the minimum required to "compile" an angular app using
//  Sass (with view encapsulation), and external HTML templates
//
var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

module.exports = {
    // Define the entry points for our application so webpack knows what to 
    //  use as inputs
    //
    entry: {
        app: ["./App/main"]
    },

    // Define where the resulting file should go
    //
    output: {
        filename: "content/[name].bundle.js"
    },

    // Define the extensions that we want webpack to resolve (we need to 
    //  override the default to ensure .ts files are included)
    //
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".js"]
    },

    // Turn on source maps for all applicable files.
    //
    devtool: "source-map",

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Process any typescript or typescript-jsx files using the ts-loader
            //
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loaders: ["ts-loader"]
            },

            // Process Sass files using the sass-loader first, and then with postcss,
            //  and finally with the raw-loader so we can convert the result into a 
            //  string and inject them into the 'styles' property of components (to 
            //  take advantage of view encapsulation)
            //
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ["raw-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"]
            },

            // Load any HTML files into raw strings so they can be included with
            //  the angular components in-line
            //
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loaders: ["html-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },

    // Configure postcss to run the autoprefixer plugin
    //
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer];
    }
}
```

And package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "typings install && webpack",
    "build-watch": "typings install && webpack --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to write that tutorial and I found the issue after seeing your reddit comment. I'm sorry you had to find this, but I'm glad you did because I learned something to watch out for :)

The issue is in the angular versions used in the package.json. If you look closely you'll see some are fixed at the rc1 version, but others (incorrectly) use the `^` version which allowed them to install the rc2 version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",     <-- results in RC2 now
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",   <-- results in RC2 now
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",   <-- results in RC2 now
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",   <-- results in RC2 now
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
}
```

As you said upgrading to RC2 worked because this brought all the versions back in sync. RC2 didn't exist at the time I wrote that code sample, so I never hit this issue, but now I know to look for it.

Comment: Ahh well happy to have helped ya out then and thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by upgrading to the from rc.1 to rc.2 which gave me a different error:

> Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of NgZone! (ApplicationRef -> ApplicationRef_ -> NgZone).

which I then fixed by adding `import "zone.js";` t the top of main.ts, not he best solution but looks like it'll work for now